# Is it possible to generate random possible accepted grammar strings using bison for a particular grammar?

Tags: bison

I want to profile my bison based application as well make sure to eliminate the effect of cache while parsing. Is it possible to generate random possible accepted grammar strings using bison for a particular grammar?

Comment: Bison does not have such a feature. And remember that bison has no idea what any token looks like. It's pretty simple to generate random token sequences from a context-free grammar; there are several questions about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34338773/1566221

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58223301/1566221

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52167/1566221